# Range Graph with `ggplot2` with Legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am trying to make a "Range Graph" with `ggplot2` package. I found some guides online but without the possibility to make a Legend.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)


# Dataframe creation
RawData <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Product A", "Product B", "Product C", "Product D"),
  Total_SE = c(38.9, 41.8, 39.4, 41.8),
  Polar_SE = c(1.6, 4.7, 3.9, 2.2),
  Disperse_SE = c(37.4, 37, 35.5, 39.6)
)

attach(RawData)

Graph1 <- RawData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = `Polar_SE`, ymax = `Disperse_SE`, x = Name),
                 size = 0.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Polar_SE`), colour = "#CB5416") +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Disperse_SE`), colour = "#267266") +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Surface energy (mN/m)") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.position="top")

Graph1
```

As you see, the Legend is not printed. I think I should unpivot the dataframe but then how can I specify the data into the graph?
Maybe there is another easier trick to chieve this?

[image]

Comment: First of all, what do you want to show in the legend?

Comment: `Polar_SE` with the red dot and `Disperse_SE` with the green dot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your legend is invisible, because you are plotting 2 columns separately, each of them is understood by ggplot2 as a separate variable. To override this you might want to reshape your data from wide to long and then plot them. Here is an example:

```
RawData2 <- RawData

RawData2$Total_SE <- NULL # drop unplotted variable

# Reshape from wide to long
RawData2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(RawData2, cols = c(Polar_SE, Disperse_SE), names_to = "param", values_to = "value")

#plot the graph
Graph2 <- ggplot2::ggplot(RawData2, aes(y=Name, x=value, color=param, group=Name)) + 
  ggplot2::geom_line(color = "grey") +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::xlab("Surface energy (mN/m)") +
  ggplot2::scale_color_manual(values=c("#267266","#CB5416")) +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.position="right")

Graph2
```

[image]

EDIT: after I pasted my answer, I realized that you wanted to have your legend on the top, but this can be adjusted easily from that point.

Comment: This is also an interesting way of doing it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a legend, you should add an aesthetic like `color`. You can give it a key legend name and use `scale_color_manual` to change the colors like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

Graph1 <- RawData %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Name)) +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = `Polar_SE`, ymax = `Disperse_SE`, x = Name),
                 size = 0.5, alpha = 0.25) +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Polar_SE`, colour = "Polar_SE")) +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Disperse_SE`, colour = "Disperse_SE")) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c('#CB5416', '#267266')) +
  coord_flip() +
  ylab("Surface energy (mN/m)") +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(), legend.position="top")

Graph1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot! The system understands that the colours have to be put into the Legend because of the definition: `name = "Legend"`?

Comment: Hi @GiacomoDB, No the `name = "Legend"` is just to give the legend a name. You don't need that. The system knows that th colors have to be put because of mentioning `colour` in your `aes` of `geom_point`.